# Event run only once

Tags: html, jquery, jquery-events

I have a script that when is clicked, it runs a function with an ajax request.

```
jQuery('.go').on('click', function(){ 
    id = "";
    id = $(this).parent().parent().find("input").val();             
    request_event("go",id);
    });
jQuery('.noGo').on('click', function(){ 
    id = "";
    id = $(this).parent().parent().find("input").val();             
    request_event("noGo",id);
});
```

After run the ajax, the value in the div (that div that contain the span value) is changed.

```
 switch(operation){
    case "go":  
       jQuery('.eventBox input[value="'+id+'"]').parent().find("#confirmBox").html("<span class='noGo cursorIcon'>N&atilde;o Confirmar</span>");
                
break;
case "noGo":
    jQuery('.eventBox input[value="'+id+'"]').parent().find("#confirmBox").html("<span class='go cursorIcon'>Confirmar</span>");

                    
break;
  }
```

The problem is that in all new "links", the on click event is not triggered.

Can anyone tell me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For all the new links, you need to do this:

```
jQuery(document).one('click', '.go', function () {
    id = "";
    id = $(this).parent().parent().find("input").val();
    request_event("go", id);
});
```

Comment: this workd but you click a second time, the event runs twice.

Comment: You want the click event to run only once?

Comment: yes. one time for each click. exemple: now you click 1 time - run 1 ajax request. clicked the second time - run 2 ajax request with the same values. clicked the third time - runs 3 ajax request with the same values and go on...

Comment: It was not the perfect solution but it work better then the mine. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Use `.on()` on the closest static element or the document like this for newly created elements

```
jQuery(document).on('click','.go', function(){
```

Comment: Right idea, wrong execution - you need to pass a selector after the event type to set up event delegation.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist Thanks, i forgot to add that

Comment: like i said to Palash Mondal, when i clicked 3 times, the event 3 time at once.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like to get "on" event register for dynamic elements, the implementation needs to be a bit different like this

```
$(document).on("click",".go",function(){
    alert("hello");
    $('#divTest').append("<span class='go'>dynamic span</span>");
});
```

Check this in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8VJAf/)